# JSF, Richfaces throwing exception & not rendering on Tomcat EE

Tags: jsf, richfaces, apache-tomee

I am not able to see any JSF components.  It shows a runtime exception:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/account/login.xhtml]
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.markResourceRendered(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createMappedResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:366)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:343)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptRenderer.encodeEnd(ScriptRenderer.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1670)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:269)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.richfaces.services.ServiceTracker$1.invoke(ServiceTracker.java:153)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/faces/context/FacesContext"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.ResourceUtils.getRenderedScriptResources(ResourceUtils.java:104)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.ResourceUtils.markScriptAsRendered(ResourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.richfaces.resource.external.ResourceTrackerForMyFaces.markResourceRendered(ResourceTrackerForMyFaces.java:71)
    at org.richfaces.resource.external.ResourceTrackerImpl.markResourceRendered(ResourceTrackerImpl.java:60)
    ... 44 more

Nov 03, 2014 10:12:25 AM com.capexil.web.controller.exception.CapexilExceptionHandler handle
SEVERE: System Error
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.markResourceRendered(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createMappedResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:366)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:343)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptRenderer.encodeEnd(ScriptRenderer.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1670)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>my-work</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>account/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
        <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>86400000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>plain</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.clientSideStyle</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>2592000000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>less</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>tff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>otf</extension>
        <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Am not able to figure what could be the problem. I am using Tomcat-EE (Tomee) 1.7.1. 
I would appreciate any help in the regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE twice in there but that's probably not the issue. What version of RichFaces do you use? Is there a specific component on the page that causes this? (I.e. if you remove it you get no exception).

Comment: Your libraries and classpath are both messed up.  You need to clean up your classpath of duplicate libraries and ensure you're not manually installing any jars that TomEE provides by default

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, yes it was case of duplicate library  - It worked when I removed libraries 'org.richfaces' from resources which may have caused the conflict, hence the exception.

Thanks!